# Microsoft Sculpt Keyboard doesn't work on macOS Sierra

Tags: mac, keyboard, macos, microsoft

I have a MacBook Pro 2010 and I bought the Sculpt keyboard but I can't get it working!

The keyboard just doesn't exist for macOS Sierra.

I searched for drivers, tutorials, etc., but all I found were people trying to remap the keys. I wish I had this problem too, because that could mean that the keyboard at least was recognized by OS...

Does anyone has any tip or trick to make it work? Where to begin?

[image]

Comment: Can you not use the keyboard at all or just not the Sculpt-specific functionality?

Comment: Does the mac see the nano transceiver as shown in this article?  http://chrissvec.com/configuring-microsoft-sculpt-keyboard-for-mac/

Comment: You might try switching your os temporarily to English.  Should not matter, but sometimes there are bugs like that...

Comment: @patrix Just Sculpt, other regular bluetooth or usb Keyboards works well. Thanks for helping

Comment: @TomGewecke When I Installed Karabiner, It appears, but nothing else works, seems like it is disabled. I'm going to try changing the language this evening to see what happens. Tks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your Macbook, but I got it to work with a late 2016 Macbook Pro with an adapter to go from the USB-C ports to the traditional Type-A USB-Ports. (Hyperdrive by Sanho) So far the Microsoft Sculpt works very well. (Some of the PC-only Fn keys don't work e.g. the search button, but it's not a major issue)

I used Karabiner Elements to change the key assignment a bit. I can recommend this guide: https://www.themtparty.com/archives/6286