# Microsoft Sculpt Keyboard becomes unresponsive intermittently on mac

Tags: keyboard

I have a macbook pro running OS X v10.13.6 and am using the microsoft sculpt keyboard with it. The keyboard works but would become unresponsive intermittently. This is the setting I see in System Information:

[image]

I did some search and found some related links but:

- [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285874/microsoft-sculpt-keyboard-unresponsive-on-mac-os-sierra) one says its completely unresponsive which is not what I am experiencing
- [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144395/microsoft-sculpt-keyboard-on-os-x?noredirect=1&lq=1) one also does not help
- Over [here](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/sculpt-ergonomic-desktop/l5v-00001#specsColumns-os) I can see 10.13.6 is not listed but am guessing that's just because its outdated and the info needs to be updated
- [This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281557/microsoft-sculpt-keyboard-doesnt-work-on-macos-sierra) does not help
- [This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6089706) too did not help

I have listed above links as sometimes I would get a downvote saying what have you tried - so listing them to show I have done some due diligence and unable to resolve the issue.

Further I have turned bluetooth off on my mac to avoid any interference (not that it should matter)

[image]

The Keyboard System Assistant (system Preferences -> keyboard -> change keyboard type...) shows this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: and promptly you get a up vote, and do not get discouraged by some giving you unreasonably hard time.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No. I was forced to use a wired keyboard as I could no longer take it. As far as I understand the problem is with Mac not with the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB 3 hubs can interfere with 2.4 GHz dongles, like the one from your keyboard/mouse. I had exactly the same issue with a Microsoft Sculpt keyboard.

**Solution:** connect the dongle of the keyboard/mouse to a USB extension wire (one foot, or you can try 10 or 15 cm as well) so it's farther away from the USB C hub.

**Lesson learned:**
never connect a 2.4GHz dongle directly to a USB C hub.

**Problematic setup:**
Mac -> USB C hub -> dongle

**Setup:**
Mac -> USB C hub -> USB extension wire -> dongle

**Alternative setup:**
Mac -> USB C hub -> USB A or B hub -> dongle

Sources:
https://www.reddit.com/r/technology/comments/136g7y/usb_30_has_been_found_to_cause_interference_that/

My setup uses an old (passive) USB hub where I connected the Sculpt dongle plus another one (that showed the same behavior when connected directly to the main USB C hub):

[image]

Comment: can you post a picture showing the setup?

Comment: btw if one has to use a 1 foot wire, might as well use wired keyboard

Comment: Apologies, the setup is under my desk now. I'll update the main post with an extra description.

One can use a wired keyboard at any point in time, but in my case, I have a wireless Sculpt keyboard that I want to use.

Comment: I added a picture now, hope it helps

Comment: I am using wired keyboard now so no longer able to evaluate if this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution for the same problem. The problem had occurred after I disconnect usb c power delivery cable from my usb-c dongle. As I connected back the power delivery cable to the dongle, my sculpt keyboard started respond to every key typing. I guess without the power delivery cable connection, the usb receiver does not receive enough electricity to work properly. The device chain of my setup are as follows.

My 2020 macbook 13 inch >
Anker PowerExpand+ 7-in-1 USB-C PD >
Anker 4-Port Ultra-Slim USB 3.0 Hub >
microsoft keyboard usb receiver

I trust Anker hubs the most after I have tried several usb-c hubs and usb hubs from various manufactures with the same mac. Usb hubs from many manufactures have some issues when they are connected with my macbook pro but every function of Anker hubs works perfectly so far.